# No sound in the web browsers ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, upgrade, browser

I updated my Ubuntu with the latest version of packages with the update manager and after i restarted my Ubuntu, there is no sound in the web browsers anymore for eg. You tube videos run without sound although the video is fine, can anyone tell me how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Ubuntu disables some 3rd party sources, which might include some flash playback.

Go to your dash, search for "Software & Updates". Try to check "Software restricted by copyright" and go to Other Software to check software from "Canonical Partners" and "Independent" which is some third-party software as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed installing pavucontrol and playing some audio in any browser.
The application browser appears in the pavucontrol and it showed that it was playing in the HDMI board, so I switched to my internal speakers and now it works fine.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```