# No sound on the internet!

Tags: pulseaudio, browser

I tried using this code

```
gksu gedit /etc/asound.conf
```

then

```
pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

and it returns

```
name@name-desktop:~$ pcm.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.pulse: command not found
name@name-desktop:~$ ctl.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse: command not found
name@name-desktop:~$ pcm.!default { type pulse }
bash: !default: event not found
name@name-desktop:~$ ctl.!default { type pulse }
```

I've also tried what's been suggesting on a similarly asked question, [No sound in the web browsers ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361707/no-sound-in-the-web-browsers-ubuntu-13-04) but it didn't solve my problem. I can hear system sounds but no audio from browsers. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: The `pcm.pulse { type pulse }` to the `ctl.!default { type pulse }` part does not go in the terminal window, but it goes into the gedit window.

Comment: Oh, I thought so, but a window never popped up (aside from asking me for my password for administrative action). How do I get the window to pop up?

Comment: nevermind! I had to install gedit for some reason (I guess when I did last time it didn't work) and saved `pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }
pcm.!default { type pulse }
ctl.!default { type pulse }` to the /asound file, now I'm going to reboot to check if it worked.

Comment: Still no sound. :(

Comment: Why wasn't Gedit already installed?

Comment: Maybe its not pre-installed with Kubuntu. Do you know how to fix this sound issue I'm still having?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed!

Ran `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` then ran `pavucontrol` in the terminal and found out that Mozilla Firefox was silenced!

Initially when I started the program, Firefox wasn't on the pavucontrol Playback tab, after checking Audio and Video configurations and then going back to Pavucontrol, it was there and I was able to set Silence to 0!

Comment: I don't know how it is automatically muted but it happens sometimes. I was confused for some this answer helped a lot

Comment: This helped me, my browser was trying to play the sound through HDMI on my laptop for some reason (I watched something my TV at some point and switched the sound to play through HDMI).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above methods and none of them worked. Finally, I found the fix in one of Firefox's forums and only that worked. In the terminal, run:

```
rm ~/.config/pulse/*
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot.

Hope this works for you :)